# Create samba share with only write and no read permissions

Tags: backup, samba

## Use case

I'm the only user. I have an ubuntu NAS with fulldisk encryption, and I'm trying to back up my own Windows machines to that. I want to have a USB stick that I can boot from to clone the Windows drives to the NAS, but I don't want the whole backup share to be readable by anyone who may come across that USB stick with the share credentials on it. Can you think of a better solution?

## What I was thinking could work

I've been searching but unable to find what I need, everything I have found is about simply enabling write access to a share, which is not what I want to do.

I would like to create a samba share on my ubuntu machine where users have *only* write permissions. I would like them to be able to create files but not be able to read them, nor list folders inside the share.

This is for the purpose of backup. I want to have a bootable usb drive that I can boot from that will take disk images of the drives in that machine and save to the samba share, but I don't want that usb to have access to all the images.

I'm happy if it just fails if a file already exists, I will ensure the filenames do not conflict by using drive UUIDs/time.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/646442/samba-write-access-rights-without-read-access-rights-possible

Comment: See also - https://askubuntu.com/questions/534251/folder-permissions-only-allow-user-to-write-not-read-or-delete & https://serverfault.com/questions/114270/samba-public-and-dropbox-folder.

Comment: Most of the answers are showing that this isn't possible as described, the only solution that looked worthwhile was the serverfault one which suggests using the student/teacher ownership paradigm.

Comment: You could configure `ssh` to allow you to connect to the NAS, using a public key. It should be possible to configure it to only allow you to deliver files.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks, that does sound like a good way to achieve what I want. Do you have any advice or a link on how to achieve that with ssh? I know how to set up ssh access with a key but not how to configure it to only allow delivering files without shell access or access to other folders.

Comment: @NickODell I think the answer from that link might work for me, as both the USB stick and the server will be running ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask a new question. In short, ssh can be configured in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, to allow or disallow various features. The only thing I have configured is to run service (and disable everything else), that is to run a custom command. So if nothing exist (I doubt this), then you can write a custom command, and have sshd run this. You can also have more than one key, for the same user. Key1 could give full access, and key2 could be used to run the upload command. see `man sshd_config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar, only difference was that one user could write-only without reading (or even listing directory), another user could only read.

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[write-only]
  comment = Write-only access without read
  path = /smbshare
  hosts allow = 172.17.10.10
  hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
  read only = no
  write list = smbwrite
  force user = smbwrite
  force group = smbread
  create mask = 0350
  directory mask = 0350
  force create mode = 0350
  force directory mode = 0350
```

Initial access rights on server side:

```
chmod -R 350 /smbshare
chown -R smbwrite:smbread /smbshare
```

Only drawback is that if you know the exact file name, you can list it.

The following part is for a reference:

```
[read-only]
  comment = Read-only access
  path = /smbshare
  read only = yes
  hosts allow = 172.17.10.20
  hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
  read list = @smbread
```

`/etc/fstab` entries on both clients:

smbwrite (172.17.10.10), local user "foo":

```
//172.17.10.1/write-only      /mnt/write      cifs    user=smbwrite,pass=s3kr1t,uid=foo,vers=3.0 0 0
```

smbread (172.17.10.20), local user "bar":

```
//172.17.10.1/read-only /mnt/read cifs user=smbread,pass=s3kr1t,uid=bar,vers=3.0 0 0
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm actually not able to read the file even if I know the exact file name with this setup. If you try to modify or write a file with an existing name it just errors out, but I can `touch` the file to update its time, and also delete it if I know its name. Weird but almost exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Mount points only support disabling write (readonly), but not disabling read. However you may can do most of it with file permissions.
It will not be possible to stop a user from reading her own files, but you can stop her from reading other peoples files.

## You will need:

- Sticky bit, to stop users from removing each others files.
- Turn off the read bits of the directory to stop others from reading
- Set a default permission, to turn off the read bits of files to stop others from reading them.

## How to

```
  chmod +t "«the directory»"
  setfacl -m "u::wx,g::wx,o:-" "«the directory»"
  setfacl -m "d:u::-,d:g::-,d:o:-" "«the directory»"
```

## Warnings

This will not be easily used by users, consider giving **some** extra permissions. Or one directory per user.

I also don't think that this is the way to do backups. Set up a cron job to do backups every day. You may be using backups for revision control, consider using a revision control system. Sub-version (svn), is a good one for must users, and most file types. Mercurial is also good for programmers, and can be used for other file-types, but I would not recommend it for any non-mergeable files (such as MS-Office).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it's not exactly what I want for my situation. I'm the only user. I have an ubuntu NAS with fulldisk encryption, and I'm trying to back up my own Windows machines to that. I want to have a USB stick that I can boot from to clone the Windows drives to the NAS, but I don't want the whole backup share to be readable by anyone who may come across that USB stick with the share credentials on it. Can you think of a better solution?